# Issues with using .not() and :has() jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to execute a couple lines of code if the $("#s4-searcharea") does NOT have .ms-sbrow class. Please help! What am I doing wrong?

A Demo would be much appreciated.

========HTML========

```
<div class="s4-search s4-rp" id="s4-searcharea" style="display: block;">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="s4-wpTopTable">
    <tr class="ms-sbrow">
      <td class="ms-sbcell"><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

========jQuery========

```
    $('#s4-searcharea').not(':has(".ms-sbrow")', function () {
    $('#explore').addClass('minimal');
    $('#header-home-icon').css('left','3px');
});
```

Comment: ...my head just exploded from the convoluted-ness of that HTML... any chance you could narrow down your question a little more? :-)

Comment: Mm, that's a *bit* better, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of '.ms-sbrow' childs inside #s4 div.

```
if( $('.ms-sbrow','#s4-searcharea').length == 0 ){
    $('#explore').addClass('minimal');
    $('#header-home-icon').css('left','3px');
}
```

or, more readble (using children())

```
if( $('#s4-searcharea').children('.ms-sbrow').length == 0 )
   [...]
```

Comment: `$("#s4-searcharea")` can be replaced with `"#s4-searcharea"`

Comment: Thank you Cristy! It worked! I've been seeing people using .length(). It is more powerful to use than .not() or .has()?

Comment: Well .not() is a method that returns elements that don't match the selector given as an argument whereas .length returns the length/number of objects returned by your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/not/), you seem to be using .not() incorrectly.  Try the `!` operator instead.